# What's the difference between height and min-height in this code?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this code:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.header {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.footer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <header class='header'>Header</header>
    <main class='main'>Main</main>
    <footer class='footer'>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is: what's the difference between **height: 100%** and **min-height: 100%** in **.wrapper** class in CSS? In this code it makes no changes, but are there any cases when it makes a sense?

Comment: [Please refer to this stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077726/what-is-the-difference-between-min-height-and-height-property)

Answer (score 0):

`height: 100%` will go to 100% of the container height; `min-height: 100%` should expand past the container's height if it needs too.

Keep in mind that min-height is not supported in IE.